# ros2 lookupTransform() to get latest transform

Tags: ros, transforms, tf2-ros, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

In [foxy tf2_ros::Buffer::lookupTransform()](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/tf2_ros/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html#a3ab502cc1e8b608957a96ad350815aee),

```
geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped 
tf2_ros::Buffer::lookupTransform(const std::string&     target_frame,
                  const std::string&    source_frame,
                  const tf2::TimePoint& time,
                  const tf2::Duration   timeout ) const
 @param time:   The time at which the value of the transform is desired. (0 will get the latest)
```

We can use `tf2::TimePoint(std::chrono::nanoseconds(0))` to get the latest transform.  In [foxy tf2 namespace](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/tf2/namespacetf2.html#aa5259116043a712592b4442ab91e92c8)

```
using tf2::Duration = typedef std::chrono::nanoseconds
using tf2::TimePoint = typedef std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>
```

`tf2::TimePoint` use system_clock. Although we can use [tf2::TimePoint fromRclcpp(const rclcpp::Time & time)](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/5a298f908eb8e39b33309d7fad8697353f1fb5da/tf2_ros/include/tf2_ros/buffer_interface.h#L98) to convert a rclcpp::Time into tf2::TimePoint,  rclcpp::Time may be  use a ROS time, such as `RCL_ROS_TIME` time source

```
inline tf2::TimePoint fromRclcpp(const rclcpp::Time & time)
{
  // tf2::TimePoint is a typedef to a system time point, but rclcpp::Time may be ROS time.
  // Ignore that, and assume the clock used from rclcpp time points is consistent.
  return tf2::TimePoint(std::chrono::nanoseconds(time.nanoseconds()));
}
```

My question is:
1: Could we directly use [rclcpp::Time lookupTransform() version](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/tf2_ros/classtf2__ros_1_1Buffer.html#a26f7be3af375e553b81188926dd38cc2)  to get latest transform, no need to convert into tf2::TimePoint ?

2: [AutowareArchitectureProposal: Replacing tf2_ros::Buffer](https://github.com/tier4/AutowareArchitectureProposal.proj/blob/main/docs/developer_guide/knowhow/PortingToROS2.md#replacing-tf2_rosbuffer) says there is some bug in tf2_ros::Buffter, is it true ?

Thanks for your help and time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397976/ros2-lookuptransform()-to-get-latest-transform/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2022-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

1. I use "tf2::TimePointZero", it give me the last transform. This tutorial can help you :
   [link text](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Tf2/Learning-About-Tf2-And-Time-Cpp.html)
2. I don't have any problems with my foxy version with timeout = 0.

---

Originally posted by [timRO](https://answers.ros.org/users/86652/timro/) with karma: 26 on 2022-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2022-03-28**:
@timRO, thanks for your help :).  tf2::TimePointZero is defined [here line=50](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/tf2/time_8h_source.html) btw. Did you meet tf net delay is very big when playing bag data, as [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/397980/tf2_monitor-net-delay-and-hz-when-playing-ros2-bag/)